# How do I check if the input is an integer? I have issue with the output when the user enter 7 the program end

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package validatinginput;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author abdal
 */
public class ValidatingInput {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Declare variables
    int number = 0;
    int lowerbound = 5;
    int upperbound =10;
    //Prompt the user to enter an interger between 5 and 10
    System.out.println("Please enter a interger int between 5 and 10");
    while (!s.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Not an int");
    s.next(); 
    }
    number = s.nextInt();

    if (number<= lowerbound || number >= upperbound){ 
        System.out.println("out bound");
        number++;
    }else{
        System.out.println("you entered");
        s.next();

           }number = s.nextInt();


       } 
}
```

Comment: By your `// Use a while-loop to repeatedly sum...` comment, it seems you _intended_ to write a `while` loop at that point, but in fact there's no `while` statement there.  So of course the program stops after one integer has been entered.

Comment: This is wrong the comment, it is for my second part of homework

Comment: My program stop a the last Int entered, I want the program to respond to user the last int is 7. this is the output:

Comment: run:
Please enter a interger int between 5 and 10
Cat
Not an int
.35
Not an int
87
out bound
7

Comment: What message do you see if you enter a number that's _not_ between 5 and 10, like 3 or 12?

Comment: It show out bounds for the both 3 or 12

Comment: And when you enter 7,which output are you getting: 1) "out bound", 2)"you entered"; 3) nothing at all; 4) none of above

Comment: nothing at all the program end

Comment: Such as the sample run of the teacher, the user enter "cat" and program answer not an int, next enter is a 3.3 program answer not an int, then the enter is 78 the program answer out bounds and then the enter is 7 the program answer you entered. But my program stop a the 7 without answer

Comment: I think the program might actually be still running, but waiting for input.  Try removing the `s.next()` that's after `System.out.println("you entered");`. Why is that there, anyway?

Comment: I removed but still stops at the 7 int.

Comment: The `number = s.nextInt()`;` statement at the end is also unnecessary and could be causing trouble as well.

Comment: when I removed [the number = s.nextInt();] the program stop running at the enter 78.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here:

1. If the user enters an integer that is out of bounds then your program will do the following: It will call `number = s.nextInt()` (wait for more input) and then just stop (return from `main`). You need another loop that keeps going until the user entered a valid integer.
2. In case the user enters an integer you read this from the scanner using `number = s.nextInt()`. In case the integer is within range you call `s.next()` and `number =`s.nextInt()`*again*. Both calls look suspicious/wrong: you already have the integer to be read in variable`number`. There is no need to read any more information from the scanner. In fact, the calls to`s.next()`and`s.nextInt()` will block until you enter more data.

After the first `number = s.nextInt()` line you should not call `s.nextXXX()` anymore.